# textcite without forenames

Tags: biblatex

I cannot really give you a mini-example as my mini-example works but the big main file does not, sorry! So, I am posting just all my usepackage, just in case it has to anything with them:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=apa]{biblatex} 
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\addbibresource{mini.bib}
```

```
\begin{document}

\textcite{Manabe1975-fz,Manabe1967-oy} says hi. \textcite{Sherwood2010-er} say goodbye, \textcite{Simmons2010-qx} say nothing.\\

\printbibliography \newpage
\end{document}
```

My mini example correctly outputs

> Manabe  and  Wetherald  (1967,  1975) blabla Sherwood et al. (2010) blabla Simmons et al. (2010) bla

but my big file compiles

> Manabe and Wetherald (1967, 1975) blabla S. C. Sherwood et al. (2010) blabla A. J. Simmons et al. (2010) bla.

They are based on the same bib-file. Do you have any idea how to exclude "S. C." and "A. J."?

Comment: biblatex adds initials or names to make entries unique, so probably your have some other Sherwood. Check uniquenames and uniquelists in the documentation.

Comment: True! When adding another Sherwood to my mini-example, the error is reproduced. - However, the two Sherwoods are from different years, so adding S.C. to it isn't necessary! How can I remove that? Also, I have other references from the same author/year. How do I add 'a' and 'b' to the year to differ between the two references?

Comment: I managed deleting the forenames via `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` as package options in biblatex.